# Clear the publishing queue

Tags: publishing-service

When the publishing service hangs, I get a big backup of publishing jobs. I would like to clear the queue and then just do a full site publish. But it does not appear that the publishing service does not honor the `PublishQueueStats` (`/sitecore/admin/PublishQueueStats.aspx`) page. When I clear it there, it has no affect on the queue.

Any idea on how to clear the queue?

Comment: I usually clear it directly from the sql master database. Note that if you are not using the publishing service, you will need to at least perform a smart or full site publish as incremental publish depends on the publishqueue table

Comment: @HishaamNamooya Publishing_JobQueue in the databases?

Comment: I just understood the question. So, you mean that after the publishing service hangs, there's a lots of publishing jobs that are triggered? If this is the case, you can clear the Publish_JobQueue from the SQL directly. The PublishQueueStats is for the publishqueue table default in Sitecore if I am not mistaken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sitecore page `PublishQueueStats` is used to see the stats of the Publish Queue on the master, web, core and filesystem. Normally, we focus mainly on the master database as it is there that content changes and needs to be published from.

Even if you clear the Publish Queue table on the master database, it will not affect the job queue of the Publishing Service. The publish queue table is mainly used by the incremental publish to see what items need to be published.

For your case, the workaround, if no "Sitecore" way is available, is to directly go to the SQL and clears the Publishing_JobQueue.

**UPDATE**

After some analysis on the Sitecore Publishing Service assemblies, I can say that the delete functionality has not been implemented as of now (version *Sitecore Publishing Service Module 9.3.0*).

From the namespace `Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Data` with class `PublishingJobProvider`, we can see that the `Delete` method has no implementation. Please see screenshot below

[image]

Comment: Damn. Looks like it is SQL only until that is implemented. Thank you.